# How to talk about certain "free" categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, teaching

Given two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, we can describe the following category $\mathcal{E}$. It is the initial category whose object set contains $\mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \times \mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{D})$ and which is equipped with

- A strict monoidal structure $\otimes : \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E}$
- For each $c \in \mathcal{C}$ a functor $F_c : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{E}$ with $F_c(d) = (c, d)$.
- For each $d \in \mathcal{D}$ a functor $G_d : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{E}$ with $G_d(c) = (c, d)$.

$\mathcal{E}$ can be explicitly constructed in the usual syntactic way, but it is a bit painstaking to describe and I think maybe obscures the idea anyway. On the other hand, if you haven't seen this kind of thing much before it's not immediately clear that the above category exists. Is there a better way to describe $\mathcal{E}$ to make it clearer that it exists, or is perhaps belief in the existence of such things an atomic mental widget?

It seems to me the clearest thing to say is the above definition followed by a few examples of morphisms, but I would be happy if there were an elegant way of easily describing the syntactic construction which yields $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Isn't it precisely just the free strict monoidal category on $\mathcal C \times \mathcal D$ ?

Comment: @Adrien, Not quite. The functors $F_c$ and $G_d$ are not related to each other. In the category you're talking about, the candidate for $F_c$ would be $F_c(f : d_1 \to d_2) = \mathrm{id}_c \times f$ and for $G_d$, $G_d(g : c_1 \to c_2) = g \times \mathrm{id}_d$. This then gives $G_d(g) \circ F_c(f) = F_c(f) \circ G_d(g)$ which I don't want to be the case.

Comment: In that case, it's probably the free strict monoidal category on the "funny tensor product" $C\Box D$.

Comment: When I read "for each $c\in \mathcal C$", I assume you mean "naturally in $c$". Similarly, when I read "$F_c(d) = (c,d)$", I assume you mean such an equation to hold both at the object and morphism level. I take from your comment that you do not mean such things?

Comment: The reason that you _should_ mean such things is that otherwise you will write down constructions that are not well-behaved under equivalences of categories.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I do not mean such things. I can give you an explanation of why I think this is a sensible thing to do/why I'm doing this if you like. Could you give me an example of something which won't be well-behaved under equivalence in this situation?

Comment: @HeinrichD, I reverted the $c \otimes d$ part. The other edit was correct, thanks.

Comment: I think your construction itself is not invariant under equivalence, because the funny tensor product is not.  If $C$ and $D$ are the terminal category, then $C\Box D$ is also terminal; but if $C$ and $D$ are the walking isomorphism $g:0\cong 1$, then $C\Box D$ contains $(g,1)\circ (1,g)$ and $(1,g) \circ (g,1)$ which are parallel but not equal, hence is not equivalent to the terminal category.  I wouldn't be as dogmatic as Theo about saying what you *should* do, but it's certainly good to at least be aware of when you violate equivalence-invariance.

Comment: That is good to know. In my situation I really do want those morphisms to be distinct. I'm thinking of $\mathcal{C}$ as representing a network of communication channels and $\mathcal{D}$ a category of computations (e.g., types with maps, polysize ensembles with polysize circuits, etc). The intention is for $\mathcal{E}$ to a be a category of "interactions" over the network with those computations.

Comment: The morphsism $(g, 1) \circ (1, g)$ would be "compute $g$ at $0$ and then send the result to $1$" while $(1, g) \circ (g, 1)$ would be "send a value to $1$ and then have them compute $g$ on it". And these two interactions shouldn't be considered the same since they have different operational characteristics (although maybe there should be a two cell or something since they're kind of "information theoretically" the same when $g$ is an iso).

Comment: @ihm You've given me an important clue about what you are doing, and so I will walk back my assertion about "should". (My statement about how I interpret sentences still holds.) I don't know much about computations. In your categories, are their any non-identity isomorphisms?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Yes, many. Do you ask because that is the only obstacle to invariance under equivalence?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd You know, I thought about it more and think that when applied to the walking isomorphism the construction I desire should yield a terminal category. On the other hand, I want it to be the case that if $C$ and $D$ are say free then the construction should have $(f, 1) \circ (1, g) \neq (1, g) \circ (f, 1)$ (and is not isomorphic to either, if we let ourselves be in a 2-category). Do you know of a construction which interpolates between these two cases depending on what $C$ and $D$ are?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is curious, I have come up with a definition which I think is satisfactory and non-evil. Weber characterizes $C \Box D$ as the pushout of

$$C \times D_0 \gets^{i_C \times \mathrm{id}} C_0 \times D_0 \to^{\mathrm{id} \times i_D} C_0 \times D$$ where $C_0, D_0$ are the discrete categories of $C$ and $D$ and $i_C, i_D$ are the inclusions. This is evil (or at least, potentially so) since taking the discrete category is evil. However, if we instead consider the pushout of
$$C \times \mathrm{Core}(D) \gets^{i_C \times \mathrm{id}} \mathrm{Core}(C) \times \mathrm{Core}(D) \to^{\mathrm{id} \times i_D} \mathrm{Core}(C) \times D$$
then I believe the resulting category (call it $C \circledast D$) will satisfy $C \circledast D \simeq C' \circledast D$ when $C \simeq C'$ and similarly for $D$.

We can then take the free symmetric monoidal category on $C \circledast D$ to get what I want. I'm not sure, but I suspect this can be obtained by taking $C \Box D$ and modding out by $(\mathrm{id}, f) \circ (g, \mathrm{id}) = (g, \mathrm{id}) \circ (\mathrm{id}, f)$ when $f$ or $g$ is an iso. Do this definition or this construction make sense?